# In Python, can one get the path of a relative import imported after and before chdir calls?

Tags: python, ipython

I'm looking to get the path of a module after `os.chdir` has been called.

In this example:

```
import os

os.chdir('/some/location')
import foo   # foo is located in the current directory.

os.chdir('/other/location')
# How do I get the path of foo now?  ..is this impossible?
```

..the `foo.__file__` variable will be `'foo.py'`, as will `inspect.stack()[0][1]` -- yet, there's no way to know where `'foo.py'` is located now, right?

What could I use, outside (or inside, without storing it as a variable at import time) of `'foo'`, which would allow me to discover the location of `foo`?

I'm attempting to build a definitive method to determine which file a module is executing from.  Since I use IPython as a shell, this is something I could actually run into.

Example usage:
I have two versions of a project I'm working on, and I'm comparing their behavior during the process of debugging them.  ..let's say they're in the directories `'proj1'` and `'proj2'`.  ..which `foo` do I have loaded in the IPython interpreter again?

The ideal:

```
In [242]: from my_tools import loc
In [243]: loc(foo)
'/home/blah/projects/proj2/foo.py'
```

** As abarnert noted, that is not possible, as python does not record the base directory location of relative imports.  This will, however, work with normal (non-relative) imports.

** Also, regular python (as opposed to IPython) does not allow imports from the current directory, but rather only from the module directory.

Comment: What is that `loc` function? It's not a standard builtin, ipython `%magic` function, `inspect` function, or anything else I know about…

Comment: the 'loc' function is what I'm making.  It just returns the path of whatever module calls it, using the stack.  I was looking to make it definitive, but figured there was no way to do so -- which you confirmed.  :-)  Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I get it. If you really want this, what about creating an import hook that automatically does `mod.__abspath__ = os.path.abspath(mod.__file__)` at import time? That could actually be a pretty handy thing to have with long iPython sessions where you `chdir` all over the place (which I occasionally do as well)…

Comment: Huh.  That's a good idea.. ..and seeing I just downloaded the ipython code..  :-)

Comment: OK, after 2 hours playing with my proof-of-concept import hook… now I'm thinking it might be worth porting to 2.7 and 3.2 as well. It really is handy for screwing around inside iPython. I don't think it'll be as trivial as in 3.3 (where it's ultimately just a matter of patching `Loader.get_filename`), but…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information isn't available anymore, period. Tracebacks, the debugger, ipython magic, etc. can't get at it. For example:

```
# foo.py
def bar():
    1/0

$ ipython
In [1]: import foo
In [2]: os.chdir('/tmp')
In [3]: foo.baz()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-a70d319d0d05> in <module>()
----> 1 foo.baz()

/private/tmp/foo.pyc in baz()

ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

---

So:

> the `foo.__file__` variable will be `'foo.py'`, as will `inspect.stack()[0][1]` -- yet, there's no way to know where `'foo.py'` is located now, right?

Right. As you can see, Python treats it as a relative path, and (incorrectly) resolves it according to the current working directory whenever it needs an absolute path.

> What could I use, outside (or inside, without storing it as a variable at import time) of 'foo', which would allow me to discover the location of foo?

Nothing. You have to store it somewhere.

The obvious thing to do is to store `os.path.abspath(foo.__file__)` from outside, or `os.path.abspath(__file__)` from inside, at import time. Not what you were hoping for, but I can't think of anything better.

---

If you want to get tricky, you can build an [import hook](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/) that modifies modules as they're imported, adding a new `__abspath__` attribute or, more simply, changing `__file__` to always been an abspath. This is easier with the [`importlib`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) module Python 3.1+.

As a quick proof of concept, I slapped together [`abspathimporter`](https://github.com/abarnert/abspathimporter). After doing an `import imppath`, every further `import` you do that finds a normal .py file or package will absify its `__file__`.

I don't know whether it works for .so/.pyd modules, or .pyc modules without source. It definitely doesn't work for modules inside zipfiles, frozen modules, or anything else that doesn't use the stock [`FileFinder`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.FileFinder). It won't retroactively affect the paths of anything imported before it. It requires 3.3+, and is horribly fragile (most seriously, the `FileFinder` class or its hook function has to be the last thing in [`sys.path_hooks`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path_hooks)—which it is by default in CPython 3.3.0-3.3.1 on four Mac and linux boxes I tested, but certainly isn't guaranteed).

But it shows what you can do if you want to. And honestly, for playing around in iPython for the past 20 minutes or so, it's kind of handy.

Comment: Thanks!  That's what I thought, i just wanted to get an external confirmation.  I appreciate your detailed reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import foo

foodir = os.getcwd()

os.chdir('/other/location')
```

`foodir` now has original directory stored in it...

Comment: I think the OP already knows this. He wants to know whether there's a way to recover the path "without storing it in a variable at import time". I don't think storing it in a variable before or after import time is the answer he's looking for.